# Perl: Find a match, remove the same lines, and to get the last field

Tags: perl

Being a Perl newbie, please pardon me for asking this basic question.

I have a text file @server1 that shows a bunch of sentences (white space is the field separator) on many lines in the file.

I needed to match lines with my keyword, remove the same lines, and extract only the last field, so I have tried with:

```
my @allmatchedlines;

open(output1, "ssh user1@server1 cat /tmp/myfile.txt |");

    while(<output1>) {
            chomp;
            @allmatchedlines = $_ if /mysearch/;
    }
    close(output1);

    my @uniqmatchedline = split(/ /, @allmatchedlines);

    my $lastfield = $uniqmatchedline[-1]\n";
    print "$lastfield\n";
```

and it gives me the output showing:
1

I don't know why it's giving me just "1".

Could someone please explain why I'm getting "1" and how I can get the last field of the matched line correctly?

Thank you!

Comment: You could try add `use strict; use warnings;` to see issues with your code

Comment: Have you printed scalar allmatchedlines to confirm there is something there?

Comment: Can you explain "_remove the same lines, and extract only the last field_" -- when you remove duplicate lines there may still be more than one line left, correct?  Then the "_last field_" is from which of those remaining lines?  From the last one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from two errors in the code, I find the statement "*remove the same lines and extract only the last field*" unclear. Once duplicate matching lines are removed, there may still be multiple distinct sentences with the pattern.

Until a clarification comes, here is code that picks the last field *from the last such sentence*.

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;

use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq)

my $file = '/tmp/myfile.txt';
my $cmd  = "ssh user1\@server1 cat $file";

open my $fh, '-|', $cmd  // die "Error opening $cmd: $!";  # / 

while (<$fh>) {
    chomp;
    push @allmatchedlines, $_ if /mysearch/;
}
close(output1);

my @unique_matched_lines = uniq @allmatchedlines;

my $lastfield = ( split ' ', $unique_matched_lines[-1] )[-1]; 

print $lastfield, "\n";
```

I changed to the three-argument `open`, with error checking.  Recall that `open` for a process involves a fork and returns pid, so an "error" doesn't at all relate to what happened with the command itself. See [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html). (The `# /` merely turns off wrong syntax highlighting.) Also note that `@` under `"..."` indicates an array and thus need be escaped.

The (default) pattern `' '` used in [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) splits on any amount of whitespace. The regex `/ /` turns off this behavior and splits on a single space.  You most likely want to use `' '`.

For more comments please see the original post below.

---

The statement `@allmatchedlines = $_ if /mysearch/;` on every iteration *assigns* to the array, overwriting whatever has been in it. So you end up with only the last line that matched `mysearch`.  You want `push @allmatchedlines, $_ ...` to get all those lines.

Also, as shown in the answer by [Justin Schell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2687838/justin-schell), `split` needs a scalar so it is taking the length of `@allmatchedlines` – which is `1` as explained above. You should have

```
my @words_in_matched_lines = map { split } @allmatchedlines;
```

When all this is straightened out, you'll have words in the array `@uniqmatchedline` and if that is the intention then its name is misleading.

To get unique elements of the array you can use the module [List::MoreUtils](http://search.cpan.org/~rehsack/List-MoreUtils-0.416/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm)

```
use List::MoreUtils qw(uniq);

my @unique_elems = uniq @whole_array;
```

Comment: @Young  I updated the answer with the recommended three-argument `open`, you may want to take a look.  Thank you for the attribution.

Answer (score 2):

```
my @uniqmatchedline = split(/ /, @allmatchedlines);
```

You're getting "1" because split takes a scalar, not an array.  An array in scalar context returns the number of elements.

You need to split on each individual line.  Something like this:

```
my @uniqmatchedline = map { split(/ /, $_) } @allmatchedlines;
```

Comment: Also, that is just `map { split } @allmatchedlines;`.  This uses the default `split ' ', $_`, where `' '` in fact matches any amount of whitespace, while `/ /` turns off that special behaviour of the default and matches precisely one space.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues with your code:

1. [split](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) is expecting a scalar value (string) to split on; if you are passing an array, it will convert the array to scalar (which is just the array length)
2. You did not have a way to remove same lines

To address these, the following code should work (not tested as no data):

```
my @allmatchedlines;

open(output1, "ssh user1@server1 cat /tmp/myfile.txt |");

while(<output1>) {
        chomp;
        @allmatchedlines = $_ if /mysearch/;
}
close(output1);

my %existing;
my @uniqmatchedline = grep !$existing{$_}++, @allmatchedlines;  #this will return the unique lines

my @lastfields = map { ((split / /, $_)[-1]) . "\n" } @uniqmatchedline ; #this maps the last field in each line into an array

print for @lastfields;
```